# Invert enum flags

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, flags

Lets say I have the following flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo
{
    None = 0,
    Foo1 = 1,
    Foo2 = 2,
    Foo4 = 4,
    Foo8 = 8
}
```

Now I have a variable foo:

```
var foo = Foo.Foo1 | Foo.Foo4;
```

What I want to get is the following the inverted flags of `foo`.
That would mean something like this:

```
Foo.Foo2 | Foo.Foo8
```

I've tried the ~ operator. But since my enum is a int32 value it inverts all 32 bits. But I actually just would need to invert the bits used by my `Foo enum`.

EDIT:
Foo1 | Foo4 would equal the following bitmask:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101
```

If you invert that bitmask by using the ~ operator you will get the following result:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010
```

The result I would like to have would be:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010
```

As you can see. I just would like to invert the bits USED by the Foo enumeration. Not all bits of the whole 32-integer value.

Comment: For the purposes of checking for a particular flag (i.e. `if (foo & Foo.Foo4 == Foo.Foo4) ...`), the result you're getting would work fine. What scenario do you have that this is causing issues for?

Comment: I have an enumeration specifying which mouse buttons are currently pressed. I also would need to know which are currently not pressed. So it would be very helpful if I just could invert the flags which are telling me which mouse buttons are currently pressed. But I already know how to check for a flag... Just need to invert it.

Comment: If you invert the entire value then only those flags that are not pressed will be set; I'm still not sure what wouldn't work for you just using `~`. Can you post a code sample that demonstrates the behaviour you don't want?

Comment: I understand your edit, but I don't understand why you need that result. If you're trying to do something with the result that isn't working, there may be an alternative way. As it stands, you have a bunch of `1`s in data that is seemingly redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is to combine all the values of the enum and then mask it with the complement of your current value.

```
        Foo value = Foo.Foo4;
        Foo allValues = (Foo)0;
        foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foo)))
            allValues |= (Foo)v;
        var compliment = allValues & ~(value);
```

Or, you could combine the values with Linq and cache them statically for performance:

```
    public static class FooHelper
    {
        private readonly static Foo allValues = ((Foo[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Foo))).Aggregate((Foo)0, (all, cur) => all | cur);

        public static Foo AllValues { get { return allValues ; } }
    }
```

And then later:

```
        var foo = Foo.Foo1 | Foo.Foo4;
        var compliment = FooHelper.AllValues & ~(foo);
```

**Update**

If you want a generic method to combine all the flag values of an enum, you can do this:

```
var compliment = EnumHelper.GetAll<Foo>() & ~(value);
```

where basic data about the enum is cached in a lazy parameterized singleton instance:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains generic utilities for enums, constrained for enums only.
/// </summary>
public sealed class EnumHelper : Enums<Enum>
{
    private EnumHelper()
    {
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// For use by EnumHelper, not for direct use.
/// </summary>
public abstract class Enums<TEnumBase> where TEnumBase : class, IConvertible
{
    // Generic singleton remembering basic properties about specified enums, cached for performance.
    sealed class DataSingleton<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, TEnumBase
    {
        static readonly DataSingleton<TEnum> instance = new DataSingleton<TEnum>();

        readonly bool isSigned;
        readonly TEnum allValues;
        readonly bool hasFlags;

        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static DataSingleton()
        {
        }

        DataSingleton()
        {
            isSigned = GetIsSigned();
            allValues = GetAll();
            hasFlags = GetHasFlags();
        }

        static bool GetHasFlags()
        {
            var attributes = typeof(TEnum).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false);
            return attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0;
        }

        static bool GetIsSigned()
        {
            var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TEnum));
            bool isSigned = (underlyingType == typeof(long) || underlyingType == typeof(int) || underlyingType == typeof(short) || underlyingType == typeof(sbyte));
            bool isUnsigned = (underlyingType == typeof(ulong) || underlyingType == typeof(uint) || underlyingType == typeof(ushort) || underlyingType == typeof(byte));
            if (!isSigned && !isUnsigned)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return isSigned;
        }

        static TEnum GetAll()
        {
            if (GetIsSigned())
            {
                long value = 0;
                foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
                    // Not sure I need the culture but Microsoft passes it in Enum.ToUInt64(Object value) - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs
                    value |= Convert.ToInt64(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), value);
            }
            else
            {
                ulong value = 0;
                foreach (var v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
                    // Not sure I need the culture but Microsoft passes it in Enum.ToUInt64(Object value) - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs
                    value |= Convert.ToUInt64(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), value);
            }
        }

        public bool HasFlags { get { return hasFlags; } }

        public bool IsSigned { get { return isSigned; } }

        public TEnum AllValues { get { return allValues; } }

        public static DataSingleton<TEnum> Instance { get { return instance; } }
    }

    private static void ThrowOnEnumWithoutFlags<TEnum>(DataSingleton<TEnum> data) where TEnum : struct, TEnumBase
    {
        if (!data.HasFlags)
        {
            throw (new ArgumentException("The generic argument [<TEnum>] must be an enumeration with the [FlagsAttribute] applied.", "TEnum: " + typeof(TEnum).FullName));
        }
    }

    public static TEnum GetAll<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, TEnumBase
    {
        var data = DataSingleton<TEnum>.Instance;
        ThrowOnEnumWithoutFlags<TEnum>(data);
        return data.AllValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer but I actually needed something faster. I've solved my problem with just doing something like this: `(~(uint) PressedMouseButtons ^ 0xFFFFFFE0)`. But thanks anyway. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: @thefiloe - if performance is an issue you can cache "allValues" in some readonly static that is initialized once.  Updating the answer...

Comment: @thefiloe why not `PressedMouseButtons ^ ~0xFFFFFFE0` then? That's only 1 operation really.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution would be using mask of all the fields and perform a XOR operation on the remainder.
Usually you start by adding an 'All' value to your enum (this way you are less likely to forget updating it if another values are added), so in your case:

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo
{
    None = 0,
    Foo1 = 1,
    Foo2 = 2,
    Foo3 = 4,
    Foo4 = 8,
    All = Foo1 | Foo2 | Foo3 | Foo4 // magic starts here
}

var foo = Foo1 | Foo4;
var fooInverted = ~Foo.All ^ ~foo; // result: Foo2|Foo3
```

Answer (score 0):

To invert individual Enum flag try this

```
private Foo foos; 
private static void FlagInvert(Foo foo)
    {var res = foos.HasFlag(foo) ? foos &= ~foo : foos  |= foo;}
```